# optexp environment error when compiling with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-optexp

I have troubles with optexp environment. There is a code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.2,5)
\pnodes(0,3){A}(1,3){BS}(3,3){M1}(1,5){M2}(1,1){PD}
\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}

\begin{optexp}
\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS](A)(BS)(PD)
\mirror[compname=M1](BS)(M1)(BS)
\mirror[compname=M2, variable](BS)(M2)(BS)
\lens[compname=L](BS)(PD)
\optdetector[compname=Det, dettype=diode](BS)(PD)
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!20!white}
\drawwidebeam(A){BS}{M1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L}{Det}
\end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

and the result is this

[image]

and I get "MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1" error. When I remove optexp environment, so

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.2,5)
\pnodes(0,3){A}(1,3){BS}(3,3){M1}(1,5){M2}(1,1){PD}
\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}


\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS](A)(BS)(PD)
\mirror[compname=M1](BS)(M1)(BS)
\mirror[compname=M2, variable](BS)(M2)(BS)
\lens[compname=L](BS)(PD)
\optdetector[compname=Det, dettype=diode](BS)(PD)
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!20!white}
\drawwidebeam(A){BS}{M1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L}{Det}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

the result is

[image]

which is correct but optical components are behind beam. I use XeLatex. What am I doing wrong? Which packages are missing? Thank you (example is from manual "Drawing optical experimental setups" where the code works correctly).

Comment: `pst-optexp` doesn't work with XeLaTeX

Comment: Without XeLatex the code doesn't work at all. What I have to run?

Comment: `latex file.tex && dvips file.dvi && ps2pdf file.ps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pst-optexp` package doesn't work with XeLaTeX. You must use the toolchain

```
latex file.tex && dvips file.dvi && ps2pdf file.ps
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a new TeX engine you can use `lualatex`, which does nearly the same as `xelatex`. Run the following example with `lualatex --shell-escape file.tex`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf-lua}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\begin{document}
Some text before \ldots

\bigskip
\begin{pspicture}(3.2,5)
    \pnodes(0,3){A}(1,3){BS}(3,3){M1}(1,5){M2}(1,1){PD}
    \psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}

    \begin{optexp}
    \beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS](A)(BS)(PD)
    \mirror[compname=M1](BS)(M1)(BS)
    \mirror[compname=M2, variable](BS)(M2)(BS)
    \lens[compname=L](BS)(PD)
    \optdetector[compname=Det, dettype=diode](BS)(PD)
    \addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!20!white}
    \drawwidebeam(A){BS}{M1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L}{Det}
    \end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}

\noindent
and some text after \ldots
\end{document}
```

Then you'll get the output:

[image]